# val() not returning value I set with val()

Tags: jquery

I have a function in which I have :

```
$("#action_box").val("uptodate");
var myVal = $("#action_box").val();
alert(myVal);
```

The output of the alert is 0. Can you point me towards my mistake?

edit : Sorry about not mentioning anything about action_box element.

```
<select name="action_box" id="action_box" style="vertical-align:top;">
    <option value="0">{{$l.opt1}}</option>
    <option value="1">{{$l.opt2}}</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: What's `#action_box`... is it a form element? You'll have to use `html()`/ `text()` otherwise...

Comment: Don't know why people keep asking javascript code as it's not related to the HTML. `:(`

Comment: What type? `input`, `checkbox`, `textarea`? Work with us here.

Comment: You're trying to set a select's value based on the option's text? You should provide the actual outputted HTML which is what jQuery works with instead of the template btw.

Comment: Provide an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) whenever you need help with this sort of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set the selected option for a `<select>` element to an option which doesn't exist (none exist with the value of `uptodate`).

Therefore the `val("uptodate")` is being effectively ignored, leaving `val()` returning the same value it did before.

If you did `$("#action_box").val("1");`, you'd have more success.

Assuming you're trying to select the element whose text context is "uptodate", providing you're not using the [`label` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option) you can get away with using;

```
$('#action_box').find('option[label="uptodate"]').prop('selected', true);
```

However, if you are using `label`, you can resort to using the `filter()` method, as discussed in the comments;

```
$(this).find('option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "uptodate";   
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: What? Options don't have a `label` attribute.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: http://jsfiddle.net/YjLmx/. It's the value you put `<option>here</option>`.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that, thanks for info. Nevertheless, square brackets is for attribute selector and not property selector. `=]` http://jsfiddle.net/pyQCd/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I *believe* (although I admit I'm more confused between attributes/ properties than anyone), that `label` is (also/only?) an attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option

Comment: I wasn't aware of the label attribute/property for options until today, but according to MDN ` This attribute is text for the label indicating the meaning of the option. If the label attribute isn't defined, its value is that of the element text content.` which is why the label property reflects the option's text. About attributes/properties, I usually interpret it as attributes being what's written in the HTML while properties are the actual DOM element properties (even though updating one reflects in the other for some properties/attributes).

Comment: Back on topic though, one method that "works" is using the `option:contains("text")` that does text matching, problem with it is `:contains("foo")` will match `foobar`, so a safer method is resorting to a filter function (as jQuery doesn't have a native exact text match pseudo-selector due to white space inconsistencies): `$('#action_box').children().filter(function(){ return $(this).text() === 'uptodate' }).prop('selected', true);` http://jsfiddle.net/pyQCd/1/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Aha, in which case I've learnt something new as well ;). I've updated the answer with the results of our discussion!

Comment: `.find('option')` is also more sturdy than `.children()` in case of e.g. they being nested into `optgroup`s, but yes this will do nicely +1